# What will be the interval of convergence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n! x^n}{2^{n^{2}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n! x^n}{2^{n^{2}}}$ My main problem is how can I handle the denominator ${2^{n^{2}}}$? I used until know the ratio test, as I saw a factorial, but it the denominator makes it a little bit difficult.

Comment: Shouldn't be that hard since $(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *Hadamard's formula*: the radius of convergence $R$ of $\sum a_n z^n$ is given by
$$\frac1R=\limsup\Bigl(\lvert a_n\rvert^{\tfrac1n}\Bigr).$$
$$\text{Now}\hspace{10em}0\le\biggl(\frac{n!}{2^{n^2}}\biggr)^{\tfrac1n}\le\biggl(\frac{n^n}{2^{n^2}}\biggr)^{\tfrac1n}=\frac n{2^n}\to 0\hspace{11em},$$
so $R=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at
$$\begin{align}
\bigg|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\bigg|&=\bigg|\frac{(n+1)!\ \ x^{n+1}}{2^{(n+1)^2}}\cdot \frac{2^{n^2}}{n!\ x^n}\bigg|\\
&=\bigg|\frac{(n+1)n!\ x^nx}{2^{n^2}\cdot 2^{2n+1}}\cdot \frac{2^{n^2}}{n!\ x^n}\bigg|\\
&=\frac{n+1}{2^{2n+1}}\cdot |x|\\
\end{align}$$
and see what will happen if $n\to\infty?$

> Well, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{2^{2n+1}}=0,\quad\text{which I assumed you know this}$$
>   and so, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\bigg|=0.$$

This means that the given power series converges for every real number $x$. Thus, the interval of convergence is $(-\infty,+\infty)$ or simply $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I think that it will be convergent,but how can I continue it?